# 14.04 "did not install correctly" when I upgraded in VMware player

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, vmware

I'm running Ubuntu 64-bit as a virtual machine using VMware player. I was prompted to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04. The installation process was taking a while and I put my laptop to sleep. When I brought it back from sleep, the installation seemed to have finished but I was met with an error message saying something along the lines of

> Ubuntu 14.04 did not install correctly.

I haven't had any apparent problems, and appear to be running 14.04, but I'm worried the installation is messed up. Is there any way I can reinstall it so that I can be comfortable it's running smoothly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall it but first take a backup and then make live cd or usb flash drive for installation/re installation. In that you will get an option to replace or repair installation you install it as you want.

for more help on reinstallation see [this](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reinstallation)

for more help on usb installation see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)